# Equation of plane given 3 points

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to find the equation of a plane that passes through the points $A = (0, 3 , 6)$, $B = (7, 1, -6)$ and $C = (-6, -9, -6)$.

I have done the cross product of $\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overrightarrow {AC}$ and obtained $120i + 156j - 96k$

Is that the final equation of the plane or am I missing a step?

I also want to find the distance from that plane to a point but I don't know how to do that, any pointers?

Comment: One vector does not specify a plane, however this vector is the vector normal to the plane and from this you can easily find the equation for the plane. E.g. look at step 3 in the answer to this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2686606/equation-of-a-plane-passing-through-3-points

Comment: Do I have to divide my equation by the greatest common factor or can I substitute directly?

Comment: That doesn't really matter, it will give you the same equation, bacause $lax + lby + lcz + lk = 0 \iff ax + by + cz + k = 0$.

Comment: So the final equation would be $120x + 156y - 96z -108 = 0$ All three points should yield the same $k$, correct?

Comment: Fill in the points and check.

Comment: I am getting different answers for each, I must have done something wrong?

Comment: Yes, you should get $0$ for all three points.

Comment: The cross product appears to have different signs to what I am getting. I have equal signs for $i,k$-parts and opposite for the $j$-part.

Comment: Your cross product should either be (120, -156, 96) or (-120, 156, -96). Somewhere mistakes in signs.