# Equation of line in the form $ax+by+cz+d=0=a'x+b'y+c'z+d'

Tags: vectors, 3d

Let the line equation be represented as $ax+by+cz+d=0=a'x+b'y+c'z+d'$, is there any way to convert this equation of line in parametric form $\frac{x-\alpha}{l}=\frac{y-\beta}{m}=\frac{z-\gamma}{n}$.

There is one way put x=0, we can find value of y and z , then put y=0, we can find the value of x and z using two find we can find the slope. I want a simple method of solving it.

Comment: You would normally get the parametric form by solving the equations as a system of two linear equations with three variables. One variable will generally be free and can be treated as a parameter. (Otherwise, the equations don't represent a line.) Does that help?

Comment: This has been asked many times before. Eg [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475953/how-to-calculate-the-intersection-of-two-planes)