# How to determine the 3d shape formed by intersecting planes

Tags: inequality, constraints, intersection-theory, convex-hulls

**Question**

How can I optimally get the list of vertices for the 3d shape (a convex hull) formed by a set of intersecting planes in 3d space that contains all feasible solutions. Assuming that a 3d shape is formed by the intersection of the planes?

Is there a name for the problem space/algorithm I'm seeking for? My background in this area is not very strong.

**Background**

I have a list of planes in the form of A, B, C, d that follow the form Ax + By + Cz - d = 0 and I want to determine the list of vertices formed by the intersection of the planes (-d for the sake of implementation details, I don't want the minus sign to be absorbed as part of the constant). Once I have a good solution I want to create a program for it.

**Attempt**

My intuition tells me that I should determine plane, plane intersection -> line, line intersection -> point, for every plane intersection, but I feel as if this is just the naive/brute force way of doing what I need. Is there perhaps a faster way or a specific algorithm of doing this especially as the number of planes approaches 10, 100, ..., n planes?
reference: [How to calculate the intersection of two planes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475953/how-to-calculate-the-intersection-of-two-planes)

My googling so far has led me to think about using Cramer's rule, to help the issue with a more general solution, but it seems rather iterative because I can't just put in all 6 planes in at the same time. At a glance it seems I would have to do some sorting to get the list of planes that intersect with each other. The other thing is that Cramer's rule breaks down a bit and I would have to do a lot of edge case catching to ensure that I can get things working, EX: if I have two planes in 3d space.
reference: https://github.com/guiriosoficial/CramersRule

**Plane Data**

1, 0, 0, 3.3927

1, 0, 0, -3.5354

0, 1, 0, -1.8034

0, 1, 0, 5.1248

0, 0, 1, 0.8506

0, 0, 1, 2.3506

[Visualization of planes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krJJ0.png)

Comment: Search for _half planes convex hull three dimensional_ . Here's one link that might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGWt46wJ5hE

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_enumeration_problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
\newcommand\Ext{\mathop\bigwedge}
$I will describe the algebra $\Ext(\R^{3+1})^*$, which works very well for intersecting planes. This is the exterior algebra of the dual space of $\R^{3+1}$; I write $3+1$ because we are projectivizing $\R^3$ by adding a dimension. We will write the standard basis of $(\R^{3+1})^*$ as $e^1, e^2, e^3, \infty$ because the last element will have the interpretation of the *plane at infinty*. Computationally, there is no difference between using $\R^{3+1}$ and $(\R^{3+1})^*$, but conceptually the latter is preferrable.

## Projectivizing

Let $V$ be any finite-dimensional real vector space. Its dual space $V^*$ is also a vector space of the same dimension, and is the set of all linear functions $V \to \R$. To any $\phi \in V^*$ we can naturally associate a plane through the origin
$$
  \ker\phi = \{v \in V \;:\; \phi(v) = 0\}.
$$
We identify $\phi$ as representing this plane. Notice that any point $x \in V$ in a plane parallel to $\phi$ satisfies the $\phi(x) = a$ for some fixed $a$. When $V = \R^3$, the basis $e^1, e^2, e^3 \in (\R^3)^*$ is the dual of the standard basis $e_1, e_2, e_3 \in \R^3$ meaning
$$
  e^i(e_j) = \delta^i_j,\quad i, j = 1, 2, 3.
$$
Now notice the the equation $\phi(x) = a$ can be written
$$
  \phi_1e^1(x) + \phi_2e^2(x) + \phi_3e^3(x) - a = 0
\tag{$*$}
$$
for some $\phi_i \in \R^3$. Formally, we can add a new dimension $\oslash = e_4$ to make $\R^{3+1}$ and form the dual basis of $e_1, e_2, e_3, \oslash$ as $e^1, e^2, e^3, \infty$. We embed $x \in \R^3$ as $x + \oslash \in \R^{3+1}$, where then we can write ($*$) as
$$
  \phi_1e^1(x+\oslash) + \phi_2e^2(x+\oslash) + \phi_3e^3(x+\oslash) - a\infty(x +\oslash) = 0.
$$
Thus we consider the element $\Phi \in (\R^{3+1})^*$
$$
  \Phi = \phi_1e^1 + \phi_2e^2 + \phi_3e^3 - a\infty.
$$
An arbitrary $x + b\oslash \in \R^{3+1}$ can be identified with a point by rescaling to $x/b + \oslash$ when $b\ne0$, in which case $\ker\phi'$ is well-defined:
$$
  \Phi(x + b\oslash) = 0 \iff \Phi(x/b + \oslash) = 0 \iff \phi(x/b) = a.
$$
If $b = 0$ then notice that
$$
  \Phi(x) = 0 \iff \Phi = -a\infty
$$
so we can identify $x$ as a point contained in the plane at infinity.

Thus we have show that elements of $(\R^{3+1})^*$ represent *arbitrary* planes in $\R^3$, not just those through the origin. In fact, we have shown that a plane defined by the equation
$$
  Ax + By + Cz - d = 0
$$
can be represented by
$$
  Ae^1 + Be^2 + Ce^3 - d\infty \in (\R^{3+1})^*.
$$

The same story repeats in arbitrary $V$, though now we talk about *hyperplanes* instead of planes.

## The Exterior Algebra

The exterior algebra $\Ext V$ is the associative algebra generated by $V$ as a subset subject only to the relations $v\wedge v = 0$ for all $v \in V$; traditionally we use $\wedge$ to write the algebra product. This condition is equivalent to the condition the all vectors anticommute with each other. $\Ext V$ naturally becomes an algebra of *subspaces* of $V$ due to the following property:
$$
  v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_k = 0 \iff v_1,\dotsc, v_k\text{ are linearly dependent}
$$
where $v_1,\dotsc, v_k \in V$. This makes an element $X = v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_k$, called a *$k$-blade*, a representation of the following subspace of $V$:
$$
  [X] = \{v \in V \;:\; v\wedge X = 0\}.
$$
Thus we can think of $v_1$ as representing a line through the origin, $v_1\wedge v_2$ the plane through the origin spanned by those vectors, $v_1\wedge v_2\wedge v_3$ a 3D space, etc.

We can just as easily form the exterior algebra $\Ext V^*$ of $V^*$. There is an intimate relation between $\Ext V^*$ and $\Ext V$ given by the existence of the following natural bilinear pairing $\Ext V^*\times\Ext V \to \R$:
$$
  (\phi_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge\phi_k,\; v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_l)
    \mapsto \delta_{kl}\det\Bigl(\phi_i(v_i)\Bigr)_{i,j=1}^k.
$$
Extending this by linearity is enough to define the full pairing. This pairing is zero when $k \ne l$ and otherwise is the determinant of the matrix with entries $\phi_i(v_j)$. Delving into this pairing is too much to get into here, but what we can find is the following: *dual* to the interpretation of $\Ext V$ as building up subspaces by spanning lines, the algebra $\Ext V^*$ builds subspaces as *intersections of (hyper)planes*.

Let's return to $V = \R^3$. Elements $\phi_1, \phi_2 \in (\R^3)^*$ are planes through the origin; then $\phi_1\wedge\phi_2$ represents the *intersection* of those planes, which is a line through the origin. This interpretation does indeed carry over to $\Ext(\R^{3+1})^*$, where elements $\Phi_1, \Phi_2, \Phi_3 \in (\R^{3+1})^*$ are arbitrary planes that need not pass through the origin. $\Phi_1\wedge\Phi_2$ is the line formed by intersecting those planes, and $\Phi_1\wedge\Phi_2\wedge\Phi_3$ is the **point of interesection** of those three planes.

We should look a little closer at these 3-blades. Since $e^1, e^2, e^3, \infty$ is our basis for $(\R^{3+1})^*$, a basis for the 3-blades is
$$
  \oslash = e^1\wedge e^2\wedge e^3,\quad E^1 =  e^2\wedge e^3\wedge\infty,\quad E^2 = e^3\wedge e^1\wedge\infty,\quad E^3 = e^1\wedge e^2\wedge\infty.
$$
$e^1$ is the $yz$-plane, $e^2$ the $zx$-plane, and $e^3$ the $xy$-plane; it follows easily that $\oslash$ is the origin (and is closely related to the other object we gave this symbol to). We see the remaining basis elements intersect $\infty$; these are *ideal points*, which we can understood as a representation of *pure displacements*. You'll find that e.g.
$$
  \oslash + E^1
$$
is exactly the point 1 unit away from $\oslash$ in the $x$-direction, and more generally
$$
  \oslash + xE^1 + yE^2 + zE^3
$$
is exactly the point $(x, y, z) \in \R^3$.

## Intersecting Three Planes

We are now able to answer the question in full. Given three planes
$$
  A_1x + B_1y + C_1z - d_1 = 0,\quad
  A_2x + B_2y + C_2z - d_2 = 0,\quad
  A_3x + B_3y + C_3z - d_3 = 0,
$$
We represent these as elements $\Phi_i \in (\R^{3+1})^*$ via
$$
  \Phi_i = A_ie^1 + B_ie^2 + C_ie^3 - d_i\infty.
$$
We then calculate
$$
  P = \Phi_1\wedge\Phi_2\wedge\Phi_3 = a\oslash + XE_1 + YE_2 + ZE_3.
$$
If $P = 0$ then

- Two of these planes are identical, or
- All three are parallel, or
- All three intersect in the same line.

If $P \ne 0$ but $a = 0$ then two of these planes intersect in a line which the third is parallel to. In this case $(X, Y, Z)$ is the direction of the line.

If $a\ne0$, then $(X/a, Y/a, Z/a)$ is the point of intersection of the three planes $\Phi_1, \Phi_2, \Phi_3$.

At this point, you can either work out $P$ by hand (which isn't too difficult, but is tedious) or implement the exterior algebra on a computer and make it do the calculation.

Comment: If you want to search for a pre-made implementation of the exterior algebra, you might have better luck searching for Clifford algebra or geometric algebra (these two being essentially the same thing). These can be thought of as the exterior algebra with a metric/inner product introduced, and the exterior algebra is just the Clifford/geometric algebra with trivial always-zero metric. In any metric these algebras also have a wedge product isomorphic to the exterior algebra.

Comment: It seems you misread the question. It mentions convex hulls, and intersecting more than three "planes" (presumably half-spaces). It is about polyhedra.

Comment: A confused OP may accept an answer that looks good, even if they don't understand it.

Comment: @mr_e_man Well, if you have the planes, then you can get all the vertices from intersecting all triples (and of course throwing out the triples that don't give you a point).  Is that not right? It seems that that's what OP was trying to do when they mentioned Cramer's rule.

Comment: I'll agree that my method above doesn't take "all 6 planes in at the same time" like OP wanted.

Comment: I see now that after getting a list of points you would have to do some testing to throw out the points that are outside the convex hull. This isn't too hard, but I would imagine all of this put together won't be terribly efficient. I'm going to remove the "perfect for this" phrasing from my answer.