# How to find a point on a triangle?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, parametric

And a happy new year to you all!

How would you calculate the coordinates of a point on the edge of a triangle?

My question is very similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2084014/how-to-find-specific-point-on-edge-of-a-triangle) but I need to work out a number of points along the edge of the triangle - not the projection of the height, as per the link previously.

Apologies, my maths skills are not strong at all.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Rudy

Comment: If you have coordinates of the corners of the triangle? If so, $\lambda A + (1-\lambda)B$ for $\lambda \in [0,1]$ will give you all points between the point $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thank you Yuki.

TBH I have no idea what that means, but I will work that out.

Comment: If I may ask, how would this example look please, if you could show me the steps to the solution?

A = (0,0), and B = (2,4)

Comment: See the answer by Siong below.

Answer (score 0):

The points along the edge $AB$ can be characterized by 
$$\lambda A + (1-\lambda)B$$ where $\lambda \in [0,1]$.

Credit: YukiJ answered this in the comment.

For example,
If $A=(0,0)$ and $B=(2,4)$

The points can be characterized by

$$\lambda(0,0)+(1-\lambda) (2,4)=(2(1-\lambda),4(1-\lambda))$$

If we substitute $\lambda=0$, we obtain $(2,4)=B$.

If we substitute $\lambda =1$, we obtain $(0,0)=A$.

If we substitute $\lambda = \frac12$, we obtain $(1,2)$ which is the mid point.

As $\lambda$ increases, we move from point $B$ to point $A$.