# Intersection of two 3D Lines

Tags: linear-algebra, intersection-theory

I wrote PHP code, following step by step by top voted comment from this topic:
[Find intersection of two 3D lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270767/find-intersection-of-two-3d-lines)

But something it's wrong and I can't find the solution.
Sometimes, the result is correct, but not always.

It's my code:

https://pastebin.com/3UBYkmnz

I think, that the problem is because I do not understand this part:

> Let l=(h/k)*e. Then one of M=C±l is the point of intersection

But h and k are vectors. How do divide vector by vector? 
I was tried to divide for example `h->x by k->x` (but what if k->x is equal to zero?). So in this case i tried to divide `h->y by k->y` or `h->z by k->z` (LINES 28 - 33).

So, for lines that are not pararell to any axies, the result is correct.
But it's wrong for line for example like this:

Line 1:

```
Given by two Points:
Point1:
x: 1440
y: 2500
z: 4500

Point2
x: 1440
y: 700
z: 3500
```

Line2:

```
Point1:
x: 1520
y: 1406.86
z: 3892.70

Point2:
x: 1440
y: 1326.86
z: 3848.26
```

Can anyone give me php solution for this problem or explain me, how to divide (h/k)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$h$ and $k$ are *not* vectors, they are norms of vectors. In the notation of the post you link

$$
h = || {\bf f} \times {\bf g}|| 
$$

So you need to calculate the cross product and then take the norm. In your code

```
$h = Vector3D::crossProduct( $f, $g );
```

calculates the cross product, but you still need to calculate the norm of `$h`