# Line intersection in 3D

Tags: 3d, intersection-theory

I have 4 points. Only three are known:

$P1(a,b,c)$
$P2(x,y,z)$

$P3(d,e,f)$

$P4(g,h,i)$

$L1=(P1P2)$, $L2=(P2P3)$ and $L3=(P3P4)$ are lines. $L1$ and $L2$ intersect with each other at point $P2$. $L2$ and $L3$ intersect with each other at point $P3$.

Length of the lines are also known as:

$L1=K$

$L2=L$

$L3=M$

On the other hand, plane's equations which contain $L1$ and $L3$ are also known.

I would like to know $x,y,z$ intersection point of $L1$ and $L2$.

Thanks in advance.
If there is any misinformation in order to be able to slove the problem, please let me know.

Comment: Possibly related: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270767/find-intersection-of-two-3d-lines)

Comment: By your definition of $L_1$ and $L_2$, their intersection point is $P_2$. Are you perhaps interested in the intersection point of $L_1$ and $L_3$ instead?

Comment: No, I am just interested in the coordinates of P2.

Comment: What to you mean by "plane's equations which contain $L_1$ and $L_3$" ?

Comment: _L1_ and _L3_ are located on different planes and equations of the planes are known (I don't know this information is needed for the solution).

Answer (score -1):

Isn't there any solution related this topic. This is a mechanism and every line is an arm of the mechanism. I need to find every position of the mechanism related to motion.

Comment: Don't post this as an answer but as a comment to your question.